# Send a mail from an external program through Outlook with no security warning?

Tags: c#, vb.net, outlook, outlook-addin, outlook-redemption

When I send a mail from my external program through Outlook, then I get the security warning.

I've tried bypassing it with secman and redemption, but both these tools doesn't allow the app to be "Any CPU".

I need the app to be Any CPU because it must be x64 on client and x86 in design (since designer doesn't allow inherited forms on x64).

So how would you go around Outlook security?

Should I write some kind of  TCP-listener-Outlook-Addin and then send a TCPIP from client with mail info?

Or how do you solve it?

Answer (score 1):

Redemption comes in both 32 and 64 bit flavors.
Your code does not need to know the bitness of your application - the COM system will load the appropriate dll.
The only limitation is that the bitness of your app must match the bitness of the MAPI system/Outlook: http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/faq.htm#ErrorCreatingRedemptionObject

Comment: We use Outlook 2007, so it's only x86 ... so I can't use Redemption in x64 with Outlook 2007.

Comment: That is correct - the bitness of your code and the bitness of the Outlook/MAPI systems must match